# Order of magnitude limit(37) vs limit(38) nearSphere

Tags: mongodb

Here is the query and explanation of my limit(37) query:
https://gist.github.com/devinrsmith/9ea1849a3f1347c55a2f

Here is the query and explanation of my limit(38) query:
https://gist.github.com/devinrsmith/7a6f8f2cd0cb6e0c3714

The limit(37) query takes ~20 millis. The limit(38) query takes ~150 millis.

Any help explaining what I may or may not be doing wrong would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is expected given how the MongoDB geospatial operators work when you request results sorted in distance order (from nearest to farthest). To avoid sorting the entire collection, the `$geoNear` or `$nearSphere` operators iteratively expand the search area in distance intervals.

With a limit of 37, your matching results happen to be found in a single inputStage (as can be seen in your explain output). A limit of 38 required an expanded search area so you'll notice there's a first inputStage which is the same as in the limit(37) explain, and a second inputStage with additional comparisons.

Depending on the density of your data set, there may be a disproportionately high number of index keys scanned compared to the number of documents returned in MongoDB 3.0.

Comparing some of the limit(37) execution stats:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "nReturned" : 37,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 24,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 560,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 299,
}
```

with limit(38) execution stats:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "nReturned" : 38,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 148,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1629,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 1084,
}
```

... the overall execution time for limit(38) is longer because the expanded search area required about three times as many key & document comparisons.

For more information on how the algorithm works (and some significant improvements coming in MongoDB 3.2), see: [Geospatial Performance Improvements in MongoDB 3.2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2).

Comment: Thanks for the info :)